# unable to view image in web mjpeg_server

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, mjpeg-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed and run the mjpeg_server in my pi 4b and ubuntu 18 machie. in pi i am using image_transport node to publish image. after that i ran mjpeg_server node in pi. But when i try to view the image in web i can't access it. When i run the mjpeg_server node in ubuntu machine i can easily access the image with url:

```
http://localhost:11311/stream?topic=/camera/image
```

But similary when i try to access the image topic after running the mjpeg server in pi with url:

```
http://192.168.4.1:11311/stream?topic=/camera/image
```

i'm not able to access the image.

Wht is the problem here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349189/unable-to-view-image-in-web-mjpeg_server/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. after i changed the port numbr 11311 to 8181 which is default port number for published images from mjpeg_server it is workng.

---

Originally posted by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) with karma: 932 on 2020-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0